# Swift 3 JSON to array of objects is very slow

Tags: arrays, json, object, swift3, swifty-json

I am upgrading my app from swift 2 to swift 3 and have a significant performance loss when building an array of custom objects.  In swift 2 this took a few seconds while in swift 3 it takes around 30 seconds.  I am using alamofire to return swiftyJSON, returning about 3000 rows of data.  the alamofire return is quick, its looping through this json to build array of custom objects thats slow.  These objects greatly simplify the code written when building table cells and passing data to new views.

Code:

```
class Customer {
var ID: String!
var sysName: String!
var address: String!
var contactID: String!

required init(_name:String?, _id: String?, _address:String?, _contactID:String?) {
    //print(json)
    if _id != nil {
        self.ID = _id
    }else{
        self.ID = ""
    }
    if _name != nil {
        self.sysName = _name
    }else{
        self.sysName = ""
    }

    if _address != nil {
        self.address = _address
    }else{
        self.address = "No Address on File"
    }
    if _contactID != nil {
        self.contactID = _contactID
    }else{
        self.contactID = ""
    }
}
```

}

```
Alamofire.request(API.Router.customerList()).responseJSON() {
        response in
        print(response.request ?? "")  // original URL request
        print(response.response ?? "") // URL response
        print(response.data ?? "")     // server data
        print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

        if let json = response.result.value {
            print("JSON: \(json)")
            self.customers = JSON(json)
            self.parseJSON()

        }
    }

func parseJSON(){
    let jsonCount = self.customers["customers"].count
    self.totalCustomers = jsonCount
        for i in 0 ..< jsonCount {
            self.loadedCustomers = i
            print("customer = \(self.customers["customers"][i]    ["sysName"].string!)")
            //VERY SLOW
            //create a customer object
            let customer = Customer( _name: self.customers["customers"][i]["sysName"].string!, _id: self.customers["customers"][i]["ID"].string!, _address: self.customers["customers"][i]["mainAddr"].string!, _contactID: self.customers["customers"][i]["contactID"].string!)
            //add customer to customer array
            self.customersArray.append(customer)
        }
        self.layoutViews()  //build view, call all table methods
    }
```

Thanks

Improved code:
    import Foundation
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

enum SearchMode{
    case name
    case address
}

class CustomerListViewController: ViewControllerWithMenu, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating{

```
var indicator: SDevIndicator!
var totalCustomers:Int!
//data arrays
var ids = [String]()
var names = [String]()
var addresses = [String]()
var searchController:UISearchController!
var currentSearchMode = SearchMode.name
var customerTableView:TableView = TableView()
var layoutVars:LayoutVars = LayoutVars()
var sections : [(index: Int, length :Int, title: String)] = Array()
var customersSearchResults:[String] = []
var shouldShowSearchResults:Bool = false
let viewsConstraint_V:NSArray = []
let viewsConstraint_V2:NSArray = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    title = "Customer List"
    view.backgroundColor = layoutVars.backgroundColor
    getCustomerList()
}


func getCustomerList() {
    //remove any added views (needed for table refresh
    for view in self.view.subviews{
        view.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    // Show Indicator
    indicator = SDevIndicator.generate(self.view)!


    Alamofire.request(API.Router.customerList()).responseJSON() {
        response in
        //print(response.request ?? "")  // original URL request
        //print(response.response ?? "") // URL response
        //print(response.data ?? "")     // server data
        //print(response.result)   // result of response serialization
        do {
            if let data = response.data,
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: Any],
                let customers = json["customers"] as? [[String: Any]] {
                for customer in customers {
                    if let id = customer["ID"] as? String {
                        self.ids.append(id)
                    }
                    if let name = customer["sysName"] as? String {
                        self.names.append(name)
                    }

                    if let address = customer["mainAddr"] as? String {
                        self.addresses.append(address)
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error deserializing JSON: \(error)")
        }
        // build sections based on first letter(json is already sorted alphabetically)
        var index = 0;
        var firstCharacterArray:[String] = [" "]
        for i in 0 ..< self.names.count {
            let stringToTest = self.names[i].uppercased()
            let firstCharacter = String(stringToTest[stringToTest.startIndex])

            if(i == 0){
                firstCharacterArray.append(firstCharacter)
            }
            if !firstCharacterArray.contains(firstCharacter) {
                let title = firstCharacterArray[firstCharacterArray.count - 1]
                firstCharacterArray.append(firstCharacter)
                let newSection = (index: index, length: i - index, title: title)
                self.sections.append(newSection)
                index = i;
            }
            if(i == self.names.count - 1){
                let title = firstCharacterArray[firstCharacterArray.count - 1]
                let newSection = (index: index, length: i - index, title: title)
                self.sections.append(newSection)
            }
        }
        self.layoutViews()
    }
}


func layoutViews(){
    indicator.dismissIndicator()
    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search Customers"
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.delegate = self
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar

    let items = ["Name","Address"]
    let customSC = SegmentedControl(items: items)
    customSC.selectedSegmentIndex = 0

    customSC.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.changeSearchOptions(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
    self.view.addSubview(customSC)

    self.customerTableView.delegate  =  self
    self.customerTableView.dataSource = self
    self.customerTableView.register(CustomerTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    self.view.addSubview(self.customerTableView)
    //auto layout group
    let viewsDictionary = [
        "view2":customSC,
        "view3":self.customerTableView
    ]as [String:AnyObject]
    let sizeVals = ["fullWidth": layoutVars.fullWidth,"width": layoutVars.fullWidth - 30,"navBottom":layoutVars.navAndStatusBarHeight,"height": self.view.frame.size.height - 100] as [String:Any]
    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[view2(fullWidth)]", options: [], metrics: sizeVals, views: viewsDictionary))
    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|[view3(fullWidth)]", options: [], metrics: sizeVals, views: viewsDictionary))
    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-navBottom-[view2(40)][view3(height)]", options: [], metrics: sizeVals, views: viewsDictionary))
}
```

/////////////// Search Methods   ///////////////////////

```
func changeSearchOptions(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        currentSearchMode = .name
        break
    case 1:
        currentSearchMode = .address
        break
    default:
        currentSearchMode = .name
        break
    }
    filterSearchResults()
}


func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    filterSearchResults()
}

func filterSearchResults(){
    customersSearchResults = []
    switch  currentSearchMode {
    case .name:
        self.customersSearchResults = self.names.filter({( aCustomer: String ) -> Bool in
            return (aCustomer.lowercased().range(of: self.searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercased()) != nil)            })
        break
    case .address:
        self.customersSearchResults = self.addresses.filter({( aCustomer: String) -> Bool in
            return (aCustomer.lowercased().range(of: self.searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercased()) != nil)
        })
        break
    }
    self.customerTableView.reloadData()
}

func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    //print("searchBarTextDidBeginEditing")
    shouldShowSearchResults = true
    self.customerTableView.reloadData()
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    shouldShowSearchResults = false
    self.customerTableView.reloadData()
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    if !shouldShowSearchResults {
        shouldShowSearchResults = true
        self.customerTableView.reloadData()
    }
    searchController.searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
}

/////////////// TableView Delegate Methods   ///////////////////////
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    if shouldShowSearchResults{
        return 1
    }else{
        return sections.count
    }
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
     //print("titleForHeaderInSection")
    if shouldShowSearchResults{
        return nil
    }else{
        if(sections[section].title == "#"){
            return "    # \(self.totalCustomers)  Customers Found"
        }else{
            return "    " + sections[section].title //hack way of indenting section text

        }
    }

}
func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]?{
    print("sectionIndexTitlesForTableView 1")
    if shouldShowSearchResults{
        return nil
    }else{
        //print("sectionIndexTitlesForTableView \(sections.map { $0.title })")
        return sections.map { $0.title }

    }
}





func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    //print("heightForHeaderInSection")
    if shouldShowSearchResults{
        return 0
    }else{
        return 50
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String, at index: Int) -> Int {
    return index
}





func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //print("numberOfRowsInSection")
    if shouldShowSearchResults{
        return self.customersSearchResults.count
    } else {
        return sections[section].length
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = customerTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! CustomerTableViewCell
    customerTableView.rowHeight = 50.0
    if shouldShowSearchResults{
        let searchString = self.searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercased()
        if(currentSearchMode == .name){
            cell.nameLbl.text = self.customersSearchResults[indexPath.row]
            cell.name = self.customersSearchResults[indexPath.row]
            if let i = self.names.index(of: cell.nameLbl.text!) {
                //print("\(cell.nameLbl.text!) is at index \(i)")
                cell.addressLbl.text = self.addresses[i]
                cell.address = self.addresses[i]
                cell.id = self.ids[i]
            } else {
                cell.addressLbl.text = ""
                cell.address = ""
                cell.id = ""
            }
            //text highlighting
            let baseString:NSString = cell.name as NSString
            let highlightedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: cell.name)
            var error: NSError?
            let regex: NSRegularExpression?
            do {
                regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: searchString, options: .caseInsensitive)
            } catch let error1 as NSError {
                error = error1
                regex = nil
            }
            if let regexError = error {
                print("Oh no! \(regexError)")
            } else {
                for match in (regex?.matches(in: baseString as String, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions(), range: NSRange(location: 0, length: baseString.length)))! as [NSTextCheckingResult] {
                    highlightedText.addAttribute(NSBackgroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.yellow, range: match.range)
                }
            }
            cell.nameLbl.attributedText = highlightedText

        }else{//address search mode
            cell.addressLbl.text = self.customersSearchResults[indexPath.row]
            cell.address = self.customersSearchResults[indexPath.row]

            if let i = self.addresses.index(of: cell.addressLbl.text!) {
                cell.nameLbl.text = self.names[i]
                cell.name = self.names[i]
                cell.id = self.ids[i]
            } else {
                cell.nameLbl.text = ""
                cell.name = ""
                cell.id = ""
            }
            //text highlighting
            let baseString:NSString = cell.address as NSString
            let highlightedText = NSMutableAttributedString(string: cell.address)
            var error: NSError?
            let regex: NSRegularExpression?
            do {
                regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: searchString, options: .caseInsensitive)
            } catch let error1 as NSError {
                error = error1
                regex = nil
            }
            if let regexError = error {
                print("Oh no! \(regexError)")
            } else {
                for match in (regex?.matches(in: baseString as String, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions(), range: NSRange(location: 0, length: baseString.length)))! as [NSTextCheckingResult] {
                    highlightedText.addAttribute(NSBackgroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.yellow, range: match.range)
                }

            }
            cell.addressLbl.attributedText = highlightedText
        }
    } else {
        //print("make cell")
        cell.id = self.ids[sections[indexPath.section].index + indexPath.row]
        cell.name = self.names[sections[indexPath.section].index + indexPath.row]
        cell.address = self.addresses[sections[indexPath.section].index + indexPath.row]

        cell.nameLbl.text = self.names[sections[indexPath.section].index + indexPath.row]
        cell.addressLbl.text = self.addresses[sections[indexPath.section].index + indexPath.row]
    }
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow;
    let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as! CustomerTableViewCell
    let customerViewController = CustomerViewController(_customerID: currentCell.id)
    navigationController?.pushViewController(customerViewController, animated: false )

    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath!, animated: true)
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Comment: You would really benefit from using the `nil coalescing operator`: `self.ID = id ?? ""`

Comment: Are you sure that assigning an empty string to things like IDs, addresses, etc. makes sense?

Comment: I'm not sure thats best, keeps the app from crashing if I were to ever try accessing.  I'm still trying to get my head around optionals and unwrapping variables.

Comment: This won't cause crashing either. `self.ID = id ?? ""` is a short hand for `if _id != nil {
        self.ID = _id
    }else{
        self.ID = ""
    }`

Comment: If `_id` has a value, it's assigned to `self.ID`. If `_id` nil, the provided default value (`""`) is assigned to `self.ID` instead.

Comment: Thanks for that tip, it will shorten all my data holding objects.  It didn't seem to make a noticeable performance difference.  looping through json to build another array seems wasteful and adds about 10mb to the memory load.  I think i will have to ditch my Customer object and just try accessing the json directly.  Would like to figure out why theres such a difference in performance though?

Comment: It's semantically equivalent. It's syntactic sugar for your convenience. It's not going to effect performance

Comment: Before you address the performance issue, I think you would really benefit from learning more about optionals. They're a pretty integral part of the language. For one, why are all those variables implicitly unwrapped optionals (`String!`)?

Comment: I managed to get the table working again, with search and sections, at a good speed.  I loop through the json and make 3 arrays of strings (id, name and address).  I populate the table with these values. when searching for either name or address I get the id by getting array index and fetching id by that index.  It was much easier when everything was wrapped into a customer object but much slower looping and creating them.  I tried making a customer a struct and an array of tuples but there was not performance change.

Comment: The custom class / struct is not the problem, your loop in `parseJSON()` is very cumbersome and inefficient. Using multiple arrays as data source is error-prone, because you have to make sure that the number of items are the same in all arrays.

Comment: Without changing the json into some kind of array, I can't get the table or search methods to work.  Is there a better way to handle the json that anyone knows of?  I am using an router to make the alamofire requsts.  I am not making use of ResponseObjectSerializable, and maybe I should be?